# Testcafe clicks on a Button customised to be a dropdown does not retrive dropdown content

Tags: testing, automated-tests, devexpress, testcafe, end-to-end

I am supposed to test a button that is customized to work like a dropdown using testcafe,
the element is successfully clicked but the dropdown content is not displayed. My suspicion is this behavior is as a result of the dropdown being a custom button and not a select, I might be wrong thou.
Does testcafe treat custom elements that should act as select the same way it treats the select tag?
If yes are there any suggestions on how to test a customs button that is designed to be a dropdown in testcafe?

Comment: Can you add your TestCafe code and the DOM?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this

but I still do not get why this does not work

```
 .click(Selector('offline-ticket-select > div > div'))
```

but this does

```
const manualClick = ClientFunction((selector) => {
      const element = document.querySelector(selector);
      element.click()
    })
 await manualClick(
      "offline-ticket-select > div > div"
    );
```